# List of objects: return object with highest attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

With a list of objects like this:

```
var products = [
  {productName: "Soap", qty: 2}, 
  {productName: "Shampoo", qty: 3}, 
  {productName: "Spray", qty: 1}
];
```

What would be the most efficient method to return the object in this list with the highest `qty`? (e.g. an alternative to use a for loop)

If there are two objects with the same `qty`, it would be ok to just return the first object with the highest `qty` in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use sort and then retrive the element.

```
products.sort(function(a,b){
     return b.qty - a.qty
})[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and get the first one with the highest quantity.

This solution needs only one iteration: O(n).

```js
var products = [{ productName: "Soap", qty: 2 }, { productName: "Shampoo", qty: 3 }, { productName: "Spray", qty: 1 }],
    highest = products.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return !i || a.qty > r.qty ? a : r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing it would be sorting and then retrieving element. Because sort is optimized on engine level and would be most efficient. I think, 95% of times, It'll use MergeSort.

```
product.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.qty - b.qty 
})
```

This will sort elements in `qty` ascending order.

See `Array.prototype.sort` docs at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It will require n^2 comparisons. It's less effective then for loop and reduce. But it definitely less cryptic (at least for me).

Comment: Yeah, now I see, it might be a very naive approach.